# Proper way to introduce a term by two names in writing

Tags: punctuation, writing-style

When introducing a term that can go by more than one name, it is common to mention the name followed by "or", the second name, and then the rest of the statement, explanation, or what have you. When spoken, there is typically a slight pause delimiting the "or *second name*" fragment from the rest of the sentence. This pause is important, as it helps to emphasize that the two names separated by the "or" both refer to the same thing, as opposed to giving the impression that you are referring to two separate, yet related things.

To give an example, I wish to express something like the following:

> A *member function* [slight pause] or *method* is a function defined as part of a class.

Where *member function* and *method* are two names for the same thing: a function defined within a class body to be part of that class.

My question is: how do you properly transcribe this speech pattern? At various points in time, from what I can currently remember, I've seen this pattern written a few different ways:

- Delimited with commas

  > A *member function*, or *method*, is [...]
- Delimited with em dashes

  > A *member function*—or *method*—is [...]
- No punctuation

  > A *member function* or *method* is [...]

Are any of these correct, or is one more correct than another? Is it perhaps even a style preference?

Comment: I'm uncertain if the [grammar] tag is a proper fit for this question, though I figure it can always be edited away if not.

Comment: Consult the relevant style manual. If none is applicable, use the pair commas by default and em-dashes where commas would be inconvenient. Since one is a phrase and the other is a single word, using no delimiters, or even an *or* would be incorrect (guess why). Just my 2c. Good Luck.

Comment: Regarding, the tags, I've changed appropriately.

Comment: You have a choice when adding a re-naming appositive. As stated at the duplicate, paired dashes (I prefer spaced en-dashes, the use of which isn't a criminal offence in the UK), brackets, commas ... or even zero punctuation. As I can't see any advantage in the added emphasis say dashes add, and in line with the admirable move towards more minimalist punctuation, I'd opt for zero punctuation here. The novel-term-italicism sets off sufficiently. Disambiguation is afforded by omitting a second indefinite article. If you think it's vital to further signal a pause, I'd say commas are sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your response and the linked question; I didn't see that one while searching.